# Avoid big spacing in bootstrap?

Tags: html, layout, task, col

I have a bootstrap page that is automatically populated using a database table. My problem is that with the current code I am using, it ends up looking like this:
[Current Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74ehA.png)

Is there any way that I can automatically move everything to look like this? [Proposed Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkTyk.png)

Current Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="block block-transparent">
                <div class="content tasks">
                    <div class="task-item priority-<%=importancecolor%> float">
                        <div class="task-item-content">
                            <div class="task-item-head"><%=rs("Summary")%></div>
                            <div class="task-item-subhead"><%=rs("detail")%></div>
                            <div class="task-item-date"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>&nbsp;<%=rs("targetcompletiondate")%>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-user"></i>&nbsp;<%=rs("assignedto")%></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you need to know that bootstrap works with grids,that is why there is columns and rows. if you want to implement what you want, i would suggest using your own custom css. the div will expand according to the length of the content.
my css and html would like like below:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Masonry</title>
 <style>
 .col-1{background: #2ecc71;width: 30%;float: left;}
 .col-2{background: #34495e;width: 30%;float: left;}
 .col-3{background: #2980b9;width: 30%;float: left;}
 .col-4{background: #c0392b;width: 30%;float: left;}
 .col-5{background: #7f8c8d;width: 30%;float: left;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="wrap">
     <div class="col-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia optio nihil rerum et deserunt tempore quidem, voluptate voluptates mollitia doloremque, excepturi cum dolore veniam dolorem? Error magnam, molestiae non rem!</div>
     <div class="col-2"> voluptate voluptates mollitia doloremque, excepturi cum dolore veniam dolorem? Error magnam, molestiae non rem!</div>
     <div class="col-3">id itaque corrupti?</div>
     <div class="col-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam fugiat consequuntur molestias quisquam nemo enim perferendis praesentium magnam, perspiciatis, itaque labore nesciunt accusantium assumenda quas incidunt aut animi veritatis cum.</div>
     <div class="col-5"> voluptate voluptates mollitia doloremque, excepturi cum dolore veniam dolorem? Error magnam, molestiae non rem!</div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of css I would have to use?

Comment: you can checkout this link in [codepen](https://codepen.io/viduthalai1947/pen/jPoVBQ)

Comment: This answer worked, but I had to redesign my structure

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a masonry style for your grid, like Pinterest does.

You may implement it using flexbox (check https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a) or, if you prefer to keep using the Bootstrap grid, try JavaScript (https://masonry.desandro.com/), altought I strongly suggest that you shouldn't use JavaScript for something you can do in CSS (if you don't have browser compatibility issues).